# Intent gallery to save un the same content?

Tags: android

I have trouble with this Intent and Gallery editor

```
  //fileURI is a content://

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/jpeg");
intent.putExtra("return-data", true); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

With Photoshop App it's ok, I can save and edit but not whith Android Gallery it save in another directory

thanks

Comment: ok only intent.getData(); in Gallery3D source :(
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/gallery3d/photoeditor/PhotoEditor.java?av=f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found :

The Gallery Source give information about noExtra is taken, only the Uri of the original file, so the only solution is to take the last File in Media Provider like that :

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
    };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
          projection, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + "="+datePhoto, null, "_ID DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long ID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID));
        fileUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik its depending on the intent itself, so the gallery maybe does not check for that extra.

Comment: No doc about what Extra Gallery get?